# Trying to verify file integrity with GnuPG. "BAD signature" all the time

Tags: linux-mint, gpg

I'm completely new to GnuPGP and I'm trying to test it.

Basically, what I've done is downloaded the Linux Mint key (`ID 0FF405B2`) from `pgp.mit.edu`.

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0FF405B2
```

I've verified that it's in my keychain, from Clement Lefebvre.

After that was done, I download the PGP block from a Linux Mint mirror. (http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/linuxmint/stable/17.3/sha256sum.txt.gpg)

I essentially copied and pasted it and saved it as `lmgpg.sig`. I've also tried `lmgpg.gpg` and `lmgpg.txt.gpg` and even just `wget`'d it.

After that, I saved one of the hashes:

```
854d0cfaa9139a898c2a22aa505b919ddde34f93b04a831b3f030ffe4e25a8e3  linuxmint-17.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso
```

as `lmsum.txt`.

So, when all that's done with, I try to verify the file with the hash in it and even the ISO itself. With both, I get:

```
gpg --verify lmgpg.sig lmsum.txt 
gpg: Signature made Wed 06 Jan 2016 08:06:20 AM PST using DSA key ID 0FF405B2
gpg: BAD signature from "Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>"
```

This also happens when I repeat the above operations with files from a Debian stable mirror.

Please, what on Earth am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various checksum and signature files allow you to verify the files you downloaded, *not* files you re-create yourself. So you download the ISO image and the verification files

```
wget http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/linuxmint/stable/17.3/linuxmint-17.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso
wget http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/linuxmint/stable/17.3/sha256sum.txt{.gpg,}
```

and pull the GPG key into your keychain as you did, then verify the files:

```
sha256sum -c sha256sum.txt
```

which complains about missing files, but verifies the ISO you downloaded, and

```
gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt
```

which should tell you that the signature is good. The signature is *only* valid for the exact file which was signed; you can't create part of it using `sha256sum` and have it verify that.

The whole point of this exercise is to verify that the ISO is correct, according to `sha256sum`, and that the SHA-256 checksum is itself correct, according to the GnuPG signature; crucially the last part relies on Clement Lefebvre's Linux Mint key which you downloaded separately from a different source.